# How do you add a subrepository properly

Tags: version-control, mercurial, subrepos

I have a repository called `main` and underneath it a number of subrepositories. When initially created the `main` superrepository, I had taken already existing repositories and copied them into the `main` folder, then added the `.hgsub` file to indicate the names of the subrepos.

Now, this `main` folder lives on our company file server and is served by `hgService`, and we need to add new repositories to it. How in the wide green world is this done seamlessly?

If i clone `main` to my local machine, then `hg init newrepo`, and copy it into the cloned `main` and add the proper entry to `.hgsub` i can commit, but i cannot push. It gives me an error along the lines of `http error 404 path not found`. Ok, fair enough so I add the entry to `hgService`'s `web.conf` file, and restart. Now i get a different error something like `subrepository 'newrepo' doesn't exist` Well duh! i'm trying to add it!

So I finally broke down and had to RAdmin to the server, manually create a newrepo, add it to the `main` repo being served by `hgService` and commit changes. This seems extremely dirty to me, and what made things even more difficult is that the state of the server's Working Directory was about 6 months out of date, I had to resolve countless problems to update it to the latest rev.

There has to be a better way of doing this.. i can't have users RAdmining in to the co. VCS server every time they need a new repository? right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately no — adding a new subrepository involves creating it on the server, you cannot `hg push` a new repository onto a server. So if creating repositories on the server requires logging into the server, well then adding a subrepository will require the same.

The `hgweb` script shipped with Mercurial (which I'll [you're referring to by hgService](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgService)) has no built-in mechanism for letting users create new repositories. The assumption is that new repositories are created by other means and `hgweb` will then serve a read-only view over HTTP and let users push/pull to the repositories with Mercurial.

There are other web frontends for Mercurial. I'm most familiar with [Kallithea](https://kallithea-scm.org/). It lets you create/delete repositories right from your browser and so you don't need to login to the server any more. This is a much nicer way to manage repositories than using plain `hgweb`.